# Aws lambda does not pickup latest image from ecr repostiory - aws sam

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using AWS SAM framework, multiple functions are defined in my template which refers to the same image URI with a tag latest in the ECR repo. When I update the image, the lambda function still runs on the old code.

```yaml
Resources:
      HelloWorldFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          PackageType: Image
          FunctionName: repayment-test-hello-axio
          Architectures:
            - x86_64
          ImageUri: 'ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/repayment-test:latest'
          ImageConfig:
            Command:
              - "app.lambda_handler"
      SettlementFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          PackageType: Image
          FunctionName: repayment-test-settlement-image
          Architectures:
            - x86_64
          ImageUri: 'ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/repayment-test:latest'
          ImageConfig:
            Command:
              - "app.repayment_settlement"
```

Running `sam build` and `sam deploy` commands shows `changeset not detected`. Is there any way to automate the image updation through AWS SAM using CI/CD pipeline.

I am aware of rerunning the `sam delete` and `sam deploy` commands, however, not sure if thats a good practice.

Comment: Changeset usually refers to the deployment template. `repayment-test:latest` is the same image Uri so it is not detected as a different image for the purposes of deploying. Usually I change the tag when I update an image to a version number or something (that way I also have something to roll back to if things go wrong)

Comment: apokryfos I want to integrate with ci/cd, so not sure how to automatically push docker images with different tags and update the same in sam template.yaml. Also rollback can be done by reverting commit and rebuilding the image.

Comment: The computed deployment template needs to be somehow different for a deployment to happen. Another thing you could do is pass `--parameter-overrides CurrentDate=$(date)` to pass the datetime of the deployment as a parameter and add this parameter in your template as well as your functions so every deployment generates a different template. I don't know if this is the best approach in the context of CI/CD though. Something I was experimenting with at some point but never went with was to deploy from a git tag and use the tag name as the image tag when building the image, though i never managed.